# Assign Ctrl+# shortcut for Chrome tabs to jump between them (not in tab bar order)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, google-chrome-extensions, intellij-idea

I use this feature in IntelliJ IDEA [Assign a shortcut for the opened tab](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-code-editor.html#tab_shortcut)  and many other editors with tab bar/strip have it too.

How it works: You press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>number</kbd>, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, to assign the active tab to the respective number. Now you surf the web and open many more tabs, but can jump back to this tab in an instant, just by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>. Useful for tabs you frequently visit, e.g. email, chat, music, superuser, docs, etc.

Is there such a Chrome extension? Otherwise I might code it myself ‒ technically it's possible.

Comment: Not exactly what you want but useful for saving the session as a whole: [Session Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-manager/mghenlmbmjcpehccoangkdpagbcbkdpc).